# How to perform analysis on a huge Excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet with around 50k rows of data and 10 columns. The sheet is about wholesalers and their products. In the current version there are around 30 unique wholesalers, each of them with around between 1000 and 3000 different products (I have queried this information from the database). What I want to do is to extract the distinct wholesalers, put them in another sheet and then for each wholesaler to find the total count of products that they offer. I was able to get a distinct list of the wholesalers (via a macro), but now I am confused how to use it in order to get the total count of their product: something like for each wholesaler do:

```
Select Count(*)
From worksheet s
Where s.wholesaler == "one of the value from the list"
```

And in general my question is what is the best way to query worksheet with loads of data? (like to use macros, pivot tables or some other excel magic)

Comment: Take a look at powerpivot: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPivot

Comment: A regular pivot table should handle that without a problem. You can also link it to the database query directly rather than using a worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a SQL query then use it :). Excel allows you to run SQL queries. See Data ribbon, External Data-From other sources -> Microsoft Query. Or checkout my SQL extension for Excel: http://blog.tkacprow.pl/?page_id=130